# child selector doesn't work with transition

Tags: css, transition

I'm having a problem similar to the following:

```
<div class="mydiv"> 
     <p>hi</p> 
     <h4>hello</h4>
 </div>
```

it works when I apply the following css to the above html. The color is getting red.

```
.mydiv:hover > p{
     color:red
}
```

but it doesn't work when I apply the following css. What is the problem:

```
.mydiv{
  transition: all 1s;
}
.mydiv:hover > p{
     transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the `transition: all 1s` to the `div`, not the `p` element you're applying transform on - You can fix this by targeting `.myDiv > p` rather than `.myDiv`

If you're trying to rotate the text inline, you'll need to apply a `width` to the `p` tag though, and changing the `:hover` to also be affecting the `p` tag

```css
.mydiv > p {
  width: 1em;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.mydiv > p:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <p>hi</p>
  <h4>hello</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: What were you looking for?

Comment: That's not exactly what I want.
When I click on an item in the menu, I want the arrow, which is the child of the item, to return. If I do it as you say, not when you click on the item, the arrow rotates when it comes to the arrow. So when I click on li, I want to return to the arrow of li's child.

Comment: I don't follow - You'll need to update your question with an example showing what you're talking about